# Use emoji as favicon in websites

Tags: javascript, html, emoji, favicon

Emojis are awesome, so I was thinking how could add one as a favicon using `link` tag.

**One possible solution:**

I found one possible way in this blog post [here](https://koddsson.com/posts/emoji-favicon/). Based on that it's been achieved what I wanted so far with the following solution.

`JavaScript` code snippet:

```
const setFavicon = (emoji) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.height = 32;
  canvas.width = 32;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '28px serif';
  ctx.fillText(emoji, -2, 24);

  const favicon = document.querySelector('link[rel=icon]');
  if (favicon) { favicon.href = canvas.toDataURL(); }
}

setFavicon('');
```

The `link` tag in `HTML`:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

**So my question:**

Maybe creating `favicon.ico` file for this purpose would do the thing also. Is there any better way to achieve this without converting or having extra `JavaScript` snippets in your code? Thank you!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Would you mind making as answer? So I can accept it.

Comment: I can certainly do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Favicon are images, so just make a static image and use that.

You're not going to change it constantly, so there's no need to make people's computers spend the time running JS to generate an asset that is always the same, better to generate it once, save that as your favicon image file, and point to that. As a bonus, browsers will cache it, so instead of recomputing it every time, or even downloading it every time, as a favicon it'll only be downloaded once and then never again.

Also note that you don't need the .ico extension (it's the extension for an ancient image format), instead just use the extension the image is supposed to have, and set the `type` to the correct image mime type.

Answer (score 31):

Now that [all major browsers support SVG favicons](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg), it's possible to refer to an SVG that contains the emoji inside:

```
<!-- favicon.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="32" font-size="32"></text>
</svg>
```

Link it up like you'd normally do:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" />
```

Comment: Woah, that's a great news, I will definitely try it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: When I used `y="32"` and `font-sizer="32"`, the rocket's edges were cut off. I mean, like if the emoji was bigger than the box holding it. Changed to 24 and now it renders fine.

Comment: @Bramus How about adding the SVG directly in the link tag? `href="data:image/svg+xml,...`

Comment: According to the link shared, so support in Safari (Mac or iOS)

Answer (score 18):

Another way to do it is:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><text y=%22.9em%22 font-size=%2290%22></text></svg>">
```

From: https://css-tricks.com/emojis-as-favicons/

Comment: This is my preferred way, as you have one less request to make from the browser.

Comment: I make small changes of `y` and `font-size` in `<text>` to make it prettier: `<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><text y=%221em%22 font-size=%2280%22></text></svg>">`

Answer (score 5):

Making a screenshot is probably the better and easier solution (as Mike mentioned).
And there is one more advantage of this solution:

Emojis can look very different on different platforms.

An example:
[image]

You won't need to handle that problem, too..

Comment: I think the look of the icon is a property of the font, and not of the system?

Comment: I totally agree. @piegames: Emojis are often provided via Opentype-SVG fonts. These font files are huge compared to regular alphabetic font families e.g "Noto Sans" (which usually don't contain colored emojis). In theory you could also provide a specific font file e.g [`Noto Emoji`](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji) but you would have to load additional data of > 6MB! So usually application use local Emoji-fonts – therefore their appearance differ from application to application as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode chars can have different width, and a `favicon.ico` should contain multiple images sizes in the same file (eq: 16px, 32px, ..., 256px).

The following Shell script will help for non standard width characters. It output a scalable `favicon.ico`, as well as the PNG and SVG version.

It accepts most full width [Unicode `zwj emojis` compositions](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-15.1/emoji-style.txt).

Usage examples:

`chmod +x genfavicon`

`./genfavicon`

`./genfavicon ‍♀️`

```
echo "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256'><text y='.95em' font-size='205'>$1</text></svg>"  > favicon.svg
convert -density 300 -define icon:auto-resize=256,128,96,64,48,32,16 -background none favicon.svg favicon.ico
convert favicon.svg favicon.png
```

Require `imagemagick`: `sudo apt install imagemagick`

---

PHP shell script version:

```html
    #!/usr/bin/php
    <?php
    // ./genfavicon 
    file_put_contents("favicon.svg" ,
      "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256'><text y='.95em' font-size='205'>".$argv[1]."</text></svg>");
    `convert favicon.svg favicon.png`
    `convert -density 300 -define icon:auto-resize=256,128,96,64,48,32,16 -background none favicon.svg favicon.ico`;
```

---

See also [How to set a temporary favicon in one-line from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407003/2494754).