# How to convert unicode character to svg and then a favicon

Tags: javascript, html, svg, favicon

I want to convert this unicode character  into svg format. Because I want to use it as a favicon. How do I simply do this?

Comment: The appearance of emoji characters is system-specific. You're probably not seeing the same character as me unless we're using the same OS. [This page has over a dozen different variations.](https://emojipedia.org/blue-book/). Instead, I think you would have more success starting with an existing SVG book icon, [like this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Book_icon_(closed)_-_Blue_and_gold.svg).

Comment: See: https://css-tricks.com/emojis-as-favicons/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One liner, set  as favicon:

```
document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("link"), {rel: "icon", href: "data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><text y='.9em' font-size='90'></text></svg>"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to learn a bit more about the character and usage in fonts, you can paste such a character in LibreOffice Calc and use formula's. Cell contents and results:

A1:

B1: =UNICODE(A1) -> 128216

C1: =UNICHAR(B1) ->

Next start Inkscape to create a SVG. Use the text tool (T) and paste the character in a new document. Modify to taste, for example, create a path of your selected character by doing Shift-Ctrl-C and change size and units of your selection. Next do "Ctrl-Shift-D" (Document Properties), choose "Resize page to drawing or selection..." (Ctrl-Shift-R) and finally do "Save as" (Shift-Ctrl-S) as "Plain SVG".

Answer (score -1):

There's free & powerful online UI tool with .svg export options. Just copy/paste symbol and in export tab choose SVG or straight @ the export put .ico extension.

Here's preview => https://www.figma.com/file/53fKioQQDobD4yVwSIMHqn/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1